# How do collect a unique list of words that end with ”ing”?

Tags: python

```py
with open("summerspeech.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for part in line.split():
            if word.endswith("ing") in part:
                print(part)
```

How do i get the right output of a unique list of words ending with "ing"?

Comment: `{word for line in openfile for word in line.split() if word.endswith("ing")}`

Comment: What is not working in your current solution?

Comment: What is `word` supposed to be in your code? Did you mean `if part.endswith()`?

Comment: Yes, we understand what you want. But what is the error that happens when running the code?

Comment: Change `word` to `part` and save the words instead of just printing them...

Answer (score 0):

Use a `set()` or `dict()`:

```
unique_words = set()
with open("summerspeech.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for word in line.split():
            if word.endswith("ing"):
                unique_words.add(word)
for unique_word in sorted(unique_words):
    print(unique_word)
```